# How do I open Windows Powershell through Python

Tags: python, powershell

I already know how to open windows command prompt through python, but I was wondering how if there is a way to open a windows powershellx86 window and run commands through python 3.7 on windows 10?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/89228/11301900

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just call out to powershell.exe using `subprocess.run`

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run('powershell.exe Get-Item *')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to run the command prompt (CMD.EXE) then you should be able to use the same method to run PowerShell (PowerShell.EXE).  PowerShell.EXE is located in c:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\ by default.  To run the shell with commands use:

```
c:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe -c {commands}
```

To launch a .ps1 script file, use

```
c:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe -f Path\Script.ps1
```

Good luck.